# Why does this import fail

Tags: python, import, module

Assume I have a project directory of the form:

```
lib/
  other_lib.py
  inner_lib/
    __init__.py <- call this [Y]
    inner_a.py
    inner.b.py
  __init__.py <- call this [X]
run.py
```

inside file `[X]`, I have the following:

```
import inner_lib
import other_lib
```

inside of `run.py`, I do:

```
from lib import *
```

This creates two module objects as expected:

```
inner_lib
outer_lib
```

However, I am unable to access the sub modules like:

```
inner_lib.inner_a
```

I can make it work by adding the following to file `[Y]`:

```
import inner_a
import inner_b
```

But I don't understand why this is necessary. If `inner_lib` grows to contain many more files, I don't want to have to explicitly import each one inside of `[Y]`.

Many thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: You only have to import them into your `__init__.py` if you  intend to access them via `inner_lib.inner_a`. You *don't* have to import them in `__init__.py` if you just do `from lib.inner_lib import inner_a, inner_b`

Comment: Suever, thanks for the quick reply.

Ideally I'd like them to be namespaced with 'inner_lib'. Why do I have to do the imports inside of __init__. Its not immediately clear why its necessary.

Comment: As far as I know, importing them via the `__init__.py` is the only way to get the namespacing behavior that you want. This is cause the members of a package/module aren't imported implicitly.

Comment: Ok. This is what I've done. Thanks so much for your assistance!